# Can I make a batch file execute a specific command based on hostname?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm writing a simple batch file to assist users in migrating their data as they move from a laptop to a new VDI machine.

I've been providing them with two batch files. One to run while on their laptop (DataUploader.bat) and one to run once they get logged in to their VDI machine (DataDownloader.bat)

I'm hoping that I can use one batch file to simplify the process. I was thinking about doing a hostname check since all of their laptop machine names  begin with the same 3 letter and their VDI machines all begin with the same three letters.

For example...

If hostname begins with PPP GOTO DataDownLoad section of batch file

If hostname begins with VVV GOTO DataUpload section of batch file

I know I could output the hostname to a txt file but I'm curious how I could use a batch file to look at that text and only use the first three characters to GOTO a specific step in the batch file.

I'm also open to any other creative solutions anyone may have other than using the hostname.

Comment: This question is too briad for SO -- read the [tour] and consult the help articles [ask] and [mcve]. Anyway, the hostname is stored in the [environment variable](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) `%COMPUTERNAME%`; the first three characters can be extracted by [sub-string expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)...

Answer (score 2):

First Things first, we will use windows built-in environment variable `%COMPUTERNAME%` to grab the *hostname* or *PC name*. From here, if you are wanting to grab only the first 3 charecters of example; `123-Johns-PC` - we can use something called [variable-substring](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) whitch will allow us to extract only the first 3 characters using the following commands:

```
Set "Host=%Computername%"
Set "Host=%Host:~0,3%"
```

For using an `IF` statement you will want to format it in the following for comparing if two strings are equal:

```
If "%Host%"=="PPP" (Goto Function) Else (Echo PPP Was Not Found!)
```

**ExecuteCommandBasedOnHostname.bat:**

```
@echo off

Rem | Gather First Three Characters Of Hostname; Save As String
Set "Host=%Computername%"
Set "Host=%Host:~0,3%"

Rem | Compare Modified Hostname String; Redirect
If "%Host%"=="PPP" (Goto DataDownLoad)
If "%Host%"=="VVV" (Goto DataUpload)

Echo ERROR: Hostname Does Not Match Database.
Echo(
pause

goto :EOF

:DataDownLoad

Rem | DataDownLoad Script Here




Goto :EOF

:DataUpload

Rem | DataUpload Script Here




Goto :EOF
```

---

I would highly suggest you take a look at some of the following commands in a command prompt to learn more about there operations and functionalities. I have left a few `Rem` comments in the script to help you along.

- `call /?`
- `set /?`
- `if /?`
- `goto /?`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this up. Very helpful. Exactly what I needed. I'm just learning some of the more advanced features so having an example specific to my use case to learn from is VERY beneficial. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to do case-insensitive code on the hostname.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "EXITCODE=0"
SET "MACHINE_TYPE=%COMPUTERNAME:~0,3%

IF /I %MACHINE_TYPE == VVV (
    ECHO This is a VVV machine
    SET "EXITCODE=%ERRORLEVEL%"
    GOTO TheEnd
)

IF /I %MACHINE_TYPE" == PPP (
    ECHO This is a VVV machine
    SET "EXITCODE=%ERRORLEVEL%"
    GOTO TheEnd
)

ECHO On machine %COMPUTERNAME%, MACHINE_TYPE %MACHINE_TYPE% is not recognized.
SET "EXITCODE=1"

:TheEnd
EXIT /B %EXITCODE%
```